# Please show close votes state for questioner

Tags: support, feature-request, closed-questions, vote-to-close

I would like to see how many close/reopen votes **my question** currently has.

The ratiocination is such that I can decide how much effort I'm going to put into it, how many people think the same as the closers, and etc.

Comment: Most of the time the closers will post a comment about why they are closing it and a recommended course of action.  I would guess they obscure the numbers to keep people from being discouraged unnecessarily.  If you see 3 close votes on something you may abandon it, but it takes 5 votes (or a mod) to close it out.  If a mod decides it needs to close you are SOL anyways :)

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work every time. I had a discussion with one commenter informing me that my question will be closed "for several reasons". That person is the only one who bothered to comment, but obviously there are more than one close vote. I know *I* would have found it helpful to see the votes and reasons.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [SuperUser FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq#reputation) section on Reputation, once you reach 250 points of rep, you have the ability to vote to close, reopen or migrate your own question. That also means that you will be able to see other people's close votes as well. The functionality you're looking for already exists, you'll just need to earn some more rep before you can use it.

Comment: I believe he's asking for the  removal of the "points requirement" for ***own*** questions..... That makes sense too actually. The information would be useful to the question poster regardless of how much rep he has.

Answer (score 2):

If the question is your own, the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq) states that you can vote to open/close and you can see the close reasons ( look below)

[image: FAQ]

If the question is not yours, and you're a 3k+ user, you can see the number of close votes on the question.

[image]

Clicking on the close link will tell you the reason for the same

[image: close reason]

So, the system does have the features that you request for, just you will need to earn the required rep before accessing them. Having said that, as JNK mentioned, most of the times, the people voting to close will leave a comment as to why the question may/will be closed.

Do note that even if your question is closed, you **can** revise it and maybe change it to a state is acceptable according to the FAQ. once you feel that you've revised it enough use the option to flag for moderator attention and drop a message stating that you feel the question is now in a state that can be answered by the community. Note that even if the moderator re-opens it, the community may vote to close again.

Comment: Your images broke — even though they are (were?!) at i.stack.imgur.com.  I thought that wasn't supposed to happen.  So, do images on i.stack.imgur.com expire?

Comment: @Scott thanks for letting me know. The images on i.stack don't expire - but soon after [se] introduced image hosting, they rewrote all i.imgur.com URLs to i.stack.imgur.com, even if they weren't uploaded to i.stack, so these come as broken